# Android XMLRPC and Magento

Tags: android

Does anyone know how I can use the Magento API to get sales data on Android using XMLRPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out the [xml-rpc](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/) library for Android.